# SQL Server Pagelock Deadlock - INSERT and DELETE

Tags: sql-server, deadlock

My client is getting a recurrent deadlock between this two statements:

```
DELETE b
FROM employees a WITH (NOLOCK), employees_prs b WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE a.employer_id = @id
    AND a.id = b.employee_id
    AND b.employee_prs = 1

INSERT INTO employees_prs (employee_id, employee_prs)
SELECT DISTINCT a.id, 1
FROM #tempdata01 b, employees a WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE a.employer_id = @id
    AND a.no_id = b.no_id
```

The resource list in the deadlock graph shows this:

```
<resource-list>
   <pagelock fileid="4" pageid="28897262" dbid="14" objectname="db01.dbo.employees_prs" id="lock373f60880" mode="IX" associatedObjectId="72057601182466048">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="process352a02988_INSERT" mode="IX" />
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="process11e0a1b88_DELETE" mode="U" requestType="wait" />
    </waiter-list>
   </pagelock>
   <pagelock fileid="4" pageid="25066463" dbid="14" objectname="db01.dbo.employees_prs" id="lock61081f580" mode="U" associatedObjectId="72057601182466048">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="process11e0a1b88_DELETE" mode="U" />
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="process352a02988_INSERT" mode="IX" requestType="wait" />
    </waiter-list>
   </pagelock>
  </resource-list>
```

I think the DELETE statement has a U lock on a page, but is also waiting to acquire another U lock on another page. Likewise, the INSERT statement has an IX lock on a page and keeps waiting to acquire another IX lock on another page.
**Is that correct?**

**How can I fix the deadlock?**

Table´s structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[employees](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL,
    [employer] [int] NOT NULL,
    [name] [varchar](30) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [employees_PK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)
)


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[employees_prs](
    [employee_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [employee_prs] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_employees_prs] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [employee_id] ASC,
    [employee_prs] ASC
)
)
```

Comment: The first thing you should do is stop littering your database with NOLOCK hints. It is NOT a magic go fast button. In fact, since you are using on deletes you are likely going to corrupt your index. Thankfully that hint will be disallowed in the future. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/ You also should consider using the more "current" ANSI-92 style joins. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: Locks are acquired one-at-a-time in order of the statement(s) until enough locks make the table(s) safe to change. I don't know for sure but it looks like you should be able to swap the tables round in the delete statement so that insert and delete both start by locking employees_prs. The first one to do so will prevent the other one continuing it lock acquisition until it is finished.

Comment: Am I correct that there is no FK between these tables? And you should remove `NOLOCK`s. Besides you have no index starting with `employee_prs`. Which means your `delete` statement needs to scan both tables.

Comment: @Lukos - you should make that an answer.

Comment: @IvanStarostin There is a FK between the tables. I know NOLOCK does not make sense in a DELETE, but I think it won´t help to fix the deadlock since the execution plan without NOLOCK s is the same.

Comment: Is there a way to debug this or simulate this speficic case of deadlock?

Comment: Review delete execution plan. You'd better put there a `tablock` hint. Try it. And I'd recommend once more to remove all 'nolocks' totally. Try it. And `tablock` - for real.

Comment: Wow! Sorry, I did not pay enough attention to the answer I waited for. Regardless other issues - you are getting the best of `FK`! Deadlock via FK is a very common issue. See, when you are inserting something to a _child_ table, server for consistency control checks if there is an appropriate (referenced by new child rows) key in a _parent_ table. Thus he needs to lock records in a _parent_ table. When a record from _parent_ table is going to be deleted - server (for the sake of consistency) must check if there are any referencing child records. And puts lock to a _child_ table too.

Answer (score -1):

Locks are acquired one-at-a-time in order of the statement(s) until enough locks make the table(s) safe to change. I don't know for sure but it looks like you should be able to swap the tables round in the delete statement so that insert and delete both start by locking employees_prs. The first one to do so will prevent the other one continuing it lock acquisition until it is finished.

Comment: You are absolutely correct about statements order, but you missed one thing - `delete` is a single statement.

Comment: The delete statement shown uses a join in the source data - it is not one statement but can cause locks on two tables.

Comment: It is a one single _statement_. Whatever it consists of and how many objects locks.

Comment: I think you have missed the point. Whatever I have called the "statements", locks are still acquired one at a time across the joins and can still cause deadlocks if the order is different between conflicting operations.

Comment: Case about _the order_ is for _statements_ - which is a specific term. It does exists but applies to _statements_. It means, order of _statements_ in your stored procedure (at first this select, later that select) does make effect on order of locking. That's what it is about. Switching places of tables in a single _statement_ will (most likely) not even affect the _execution plan_.